# Where to put data class in prism

Tags: c#, module, prism

So I understand this question could be interpreted as an opinion-based question but its a technical question for me.

In the Prism documentation, it is stated that modules should have loose coupling with no direct references, only going through shared interfaces. Like in the following picture:

[image]

My issue is for example if I have an order class in the ordersModule which define the order structure something like this:

```
public class Order 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string OrderItem { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the customer viewModel Want to have an orders list:

```
public List<Order> CustomerOrders;
```

In this case I must have a hard dependency on OrdersModule which clearly breaks the loose coupling between modules so what should I?

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Put it in an assembly and reference that from whereever needed (main app, modules...).

A module may have dependencies outside the module itself, same for the main app, and there may be assemblies that don't house a module (as there may be ones that house more than one). You have to be careful when deploying updates for modules that you do not create conflicts in dependencies (like Module1 depends on old Order.dll and Module2 gets updated and depends on new Order.dll). Basically, you'll have to treat a module's dependencies as published API.

If you think that's too complicated and you'll never update individual modules anyway, you most probably do not want to use modules at all to begin with.

Comment: So do you suggest making one assembly and putting all of the data classes in it?

Comment: one or more, that depends on your requirements